# Fitting RandomForest Model But Getting Pandas Error

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns: id, sentiment, review.  I crating vectors and I am putting it thru a RandomForest in order to make a prediction of the sentiment.

On the following line: 
  forest = forest.fit(trainDataVecs, train["sentiment"])

I keep getting the following error: 
  Error is:  ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

I got it working in a very small sample file but it refuses to work on my large main one.  I have checked and I am 100% certain there are no NULL entries.  Some of the reviews are very long and I thing what must be happening is that the review length is a problem somewhere.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be when you're reading one of the numerical columns. I would suggest that when you're reading the data from the source, you change the type to something more precise like `np.float64`, or greater, and also remove an invalid values like follows:

```
# A is the vector you want to clean
A[~np.isnan(A)] = 0.0
```

Comment: Or cleaner: `A.fillna(0)`